# How do I rewrite a function that uses a combined parameter (latlong) into a function with seperate perameters, latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to convert this function that uses a the paremeter latlong into a function that uses latitude and longitude as seperate parameters. There is a part in this function that I can't convert it when using latitude and longitude as seperate parameters. (The function that I want to convert is in javascript and I want to convert it to C#)Here is the function:

```
function inBoundedBox(latlong1, latlong2, latlong3)
  {
var betweenLats;
var betweenLons;

if(latlong1.Latitude < latlong2.Latitude)
    betweenLats = (latlong1.Latitude <= latlong3.Latitude && 
latlong2.Latitude >= latlong3.Latitude);
else
    betweenLats = (latlong1.Latitude >= latlong3.Latitude && 
 latlong2.Latitude <= latlong3.Latitude);
    
if(latlong1.Longitude < latlong2.Longitude)
    betweenLons = (latlong1.Longitude <= latlong3.Longitude && 
    latlong2.Longitude >= latlong3.Longitude);
else
    betweenLons = (latlong1.Longitude >= latlong3.Longitude && 
    latlong2.Longitude <= latlong3.Longitude);

return (betweenLats && betweenLons);
```

}

Here is some part of the converted function (in C#):

```
 public void checkIntersections(double latitude1, double longitude1, double latitude2, double 
  longitude2, double latitude3, double longitude3) 
    {
        double betweenLats;
        double betweenLongs;
        if (latitude1 < latitude2)
        {
            betweenLats = (latitude1 <= latitude3 && latitude2 >=latitude3);
    
        }
        else 
        { 

        }

    
    }
```

I'm having some trouble with the variable betweenLats. The error that I get says that I can't convert type bool to double. How should I convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the code like this. `betweenLats` and `betweenLons` will be of type `bool`.

```
public static bool inBoundedBox(double latitude1, double longitude1, double latitude2, double longitude2, double latitude3, double longitude3)
{
    bool betweenLats;
    bool betweenLons;

    if (latitude1 < latitude2)
        betweenLats = (latitude1 <= latitude3 &&
    latitude2 >= latitude3);
    else
        betweenLats = (latitude1 >= latitude3 &&
        latitude2 <= latitude3);

    if (longitude1 < longitude2)
        betweenLons = (longitude1 <= longitude3 &&
        longitude2 >= longitude3);
    else
        betweenLons = (longitude1 >= longitude3 &&
        longitude2 <= longitude3);

    return (betweenLats && betweenLons);
}
```